# Unknown property errors trying to do a with Flyway migration with per script config files

Tags: configuration-files, flyway, migrate

My company is evaluating Flyway for database releases.  We have an AWS PostgreSQL version 11.2 database and I have installed Flyway Community Edition version 6.1.2.

I have successfully baselined the database and run several basic DDL scripts using Flyway migrate.  However now I am testing a more complicated scenario in which I need to run multiple scripts as one migration but each script has to connect as a different PostgreSqL user.  I have tried to do this by setting up two sql files each with their own config file as described here: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/scriptconfigfiles

Every time I run the migrate command I get a property error: "ERROR: Unknown script configuration property: flyway.user" or "ERROR: Unknown script configuration property: user", etc, etc.

For debugging purposes I removed one sql and config combo so that I now only have one file each. The files are named V2020.1.14.08.41.00__role_test1.sql and V2020.1.14.08.41.00__role_test1.sql.conf. I did confirm that any changes to that config file are being picked up by the migrate command. My config file contains the following properties (values changes for security reasons):

```
flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://...  
flyway.user=user1  
flyway.password=password  
flyway.schemas=test
```

I have also tried removing the flyway prefix:

```
url=jdbc:postgresql://...  
user=user1  
password=password  
schemas=test
```

And removing the url parameter (both flyway.url and url) so the migration reads that value from the default flyway.conf file. Example:

```
user=user1  
password=password  
schemas=test
```

I get the errors every time.  Anyone have any ideas?  All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code:

```
flyeay.user=user1
```

It should be:

```
 flyway.user=user1
```

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately the typo was only in the transcription to this forum, which I have now fixed.  It is not in the actual code.